# How to validate the JSON key from global variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, postman, javascript-objects, postman-pre-request-script

I am new to javascript, can someone help me how can I validate the JSON key from global variables using javascript in Postman.

I want to read the dd value(1566) by passing the ID value from global variables. Please refer the screenshot attached which contains my response and the validation code written.

Comment: Please do not post code as image. Use three backticks before and after the code to put it into a codeblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change this.

```js
console.log(adLength.pm.globals.get('ID').cmps.dd)
```

to

```js
console.log(resp.data.result.asi[`${pm.globals.get('ID')}`].cmps.dd)
```